# trouble with unlink in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Im trying to unlink deleted files on my database. Data is successfully deleted but the file wont unlink.

Please help me check my code. I've search alot but I think there's nothing wrong with my code.

```html
public function delCategory($c_id)
    {
      $stmt1 = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_content LEFT JOIN tbl_files USING (c_id) WHERE c_id=:unlink_id");
      $stmt1->execute(array(":unlink_id"=>$c_id));
      $unlinkRow=$stmt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      unlink("admin/cover_images/".$unlinkRow['c_cover']);
      unlink("admin/content_files/".$unlinkRow['cont_file']);

      $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("DELETE tbl_files, tbl_content FROM tbl_files LEFT JOIN tbl_content ON tbl_files.c_id=tbl_content.c_id WHERE tbl_files.c_id=:id");
      $stmt->bindparam(":id",$c_id);
      $stmt->execute();
      return true;
    }
```

Comment: Try using absolute paths, e.g. `unlink($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/admin/cover_images/".$unlinkRow['c_cover'])`

Comment: Firstly, your delete statement doesn't require the 'left join'. Secondly, your `unlink` command is using relative path to find the file. Try doing `die(var_dump(file_exists("admin/cover_images/".$unlinkRow['c_cover']))` to debug if php can actually see the file on your server. If it returns false, then you should use absolute path to the file for your deleting purposes.

Comment: Also make sure, the directory has WRITE permissions for the executing php-user.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're calling the file from the same directory as the admin folder, try this:

```
unlink(__DIR__."/admin/cover_images/".$unlinkRow['c_cover']);
unlink(__DIR__."/admin/cover_images/".$unlinkRow['cont_file']);
```

Otherwise, you'll need to try what other's have said which is:

```
unlink($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/admin/cover_images/".$unl‌inkRow['c_cover'])
unlink($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/admin/cover_images/".$unl‌​inkRow['cont_file'])
```

Comment: unlink(__DIR__."/admin/cover_images/".$unlinkRow['c_cover']);
unlink(__DIR__."/admin/cover_images/".$unlinkRow['cont_file']);